# Why not static const references on class member variables?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a question about static references on class members in C++. It is easy to create a static const member which is a pointer on a non-static member of the same class; like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
private:
    static int A::* const ptr_on_x;
};

int A::* const ptr_on_x = &A::x;
```

Now, I cannot figure out why I cannot write something like that, i.e. make a static const member which is a reference on a non-static member of the same class:

```
//won't compile
class B {
public:
    int x;
private:
    static int B::& const ptr_on_x;
};

int B::& const ptr_on_x = B::x;
```

From the various posts in SO about différences between pointers and references, I don't find any clue. On the contrary, I even read that "references are kind of aliases". So what do I misundertand?

So is it possible to define some variable aliases inside the same class? I admit that with a simple class it doesn't seem very useful; it is a question about the langage itself.

Also I don't know C++0x very much, so does C++0x offers a solution for this?

**EDIT**
The comment of MarcinŁoś gives me another idea. You can take a function reference, so can I create a class member which is a reference on a class method?

Comment: You can't reference `x` without an instance of `A`or `B`.

Comment: @Stijn I don't realize that. `&A::x` is really a function pointer, with `x` an int? So what are the implicit casts?

Comment: @stijn nope, it gives a pointer to member. And, there are function references as well ;)

Comment: @stijn: No, `&A::x` gives a pointer-to-member, since `x` is a data member.

Comment: @g-makulik Yeah, that's the point... I can only take static const pointers of class members? So the thing is a reference can only be taken on a created object?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Ok for me. So if I can take a function reference, why not a member variable reference?

Comment: @Bentoy13 pointer-to-member is fundamentally different from ordinary pointer. In the same way, reference-to-member would be fundamentally different from ordinary reference. Reference-to-member simply does not exist, probably the Comitee felt no need to include it, especially since pointer-to-member is rarely used (or used to have been, before `std::function` and useful `std::bind`?)

Comment: oops, totally misread that.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Ok. I need to be careful about the denomination, it is really "pointer-to-member" (and dashes are important!); thus I won't confuse it anymore! Concerning function references, can I create a class member which is a reference on a class method?

Answer (score 3):

Simply because there is no such type as a reference-to-member, only a pointer-to-member.

> From the various posts in SO about différences between pointers and references, I don't find any clue.

A pointer-to-member has little to do with a pointer apart from its (slightly misleading) name, and the fact that, like a pointer, it refers to something else. There was never considered to be a compelling reason to add an analogous type that looked more like a reference.

> So is it possible to define some variable aliases inside the same class?

No, there's no sensible way to do that.

> Also I don't know C++0x very much, so does C++0x offers a solution for this?

No.

Comment: you say that _it refers to something else_. Could you please precise this point?

Comment: @Bentoy13: As a normal (object) pointer refers to an object, and a function pointer refers to a function, so a pointer-to-member refers to a member.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main confusion is that the pointer is simply an offset pointer (it knows where the member is located in relation to the struct), not an absolute pointer, while a reference is always absolute, hence you cannot do the same.